# Bulk collect into array and error handling in DBMS_OUTPUT

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am copying data from table A to table B. In table A I have four columns for countries (EN, ES, RU, UK). The column per country is a separate row in table B. In addition, each row in table B must be duplicated and receive the next sequence number.

Table A - my cursor

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Company |   EN    |   ES    |   RU    |   UK    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Intel   | 123 345 | 453 343 | 444 101 | 110 232 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Table B

```
+---------+---------+-----+
| Company | Country | SEQ |
+---------+---------+-----+
| Intel   | 123 345 |   0 |
| Intel   | 123 345 |   1 |
| Intel   | 453 343 |   0 |
| Intel   | 453 343 |   1 |
| INTEL   | 444 101 |   0 |
| INTEL   | 444 101 |   1 |
| INTEL   | 110 232 |   0 |
| INTEL   | 110 232 |   1 |
+---------+---------+-----+
```

In table A I have 1,000,000 rows. 

In Table B, I should have 1,000,000 (rows) x 4 (country) x 2 (seq) = 8,000,000.

I prepared the procedure for inserting data.

```
BEGIN

OPEN my_cursor;
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN my_cursor%notfound;
        FETCH my_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO TAB LIMIT 500;

        FOR y in 0..1 LOOP 

                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last 
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."EN", y);

                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."ES", y);

                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last 
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."RU", y);

                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last 
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."UK", y);

        END LOOP;

        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;     
CLOSE my_cursor;

END;
```

In the case of a DML error in table B, I have to return the value of variables from array (tab) together with the error code in DBMS_OUTPUT
for example:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab(x)."company" || ' ' || tab(x)."UK" || SQLERRM);
```

Is it possible to handle such errors? How can I implement such a solution?
.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can handle such errors and continue with all the insert using `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` with `FORALL` as below : 
PLSQL raises `ORA:24381` after all the statement is executed.

```
BEGIN
FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."EN", y);
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN
 IF sqlcode = -24381
     FOR indx IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
         LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                  SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_INDEX
               || ‘: ‘
               || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_CODE);
         END LOOP;
else 
raise;
end if;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your goal by using `FOR ALL ... SAVE EXCEPTIONS` instruction.
This will give you the following :

```
DECLARE
    ln_error_count NUMBER;
    ln_line_error  NUMBER;
BEGIN

    OPEN my_cursor;
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN my_cursor%notfound;
        FETCH my_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO TAB LIMIT 500;

        FOR y in 0..1 LOOP

            BEGIN
                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."EN", y);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
                    ln_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
                    FOR i IN 1 .. ln_error_count LOOP
                        ln_line_error := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index;
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab(ln_line_error)."company" || ' ' || tab(ln_line_error)."EN" || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
                    END LOOP;
            END;

            BEGIN
                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."ES", y);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
                    ln_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
                    FOR i IN 1 .. ln_error_count LOOP
                        ln_line_error := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index;
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab(ln_line_error)."company" || ' ' || tab(ln_line_error)."ES" || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
                    END LOOP;
                END;

            BEGIN
                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."RU", y);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
                    ln_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
                    FOR i IN 1 .. ln_error_count LOOP
                        ln_line_error := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index;
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab(ln_line_error)."company" || ' ' || tab(ln_line_error)."RU" || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
                    END LOOP;
            END;

            BEGIN
                FORALL x IN TAB.first..TAB.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                    INSERT INTO table_B ("company","country","seq") VALUES (tab(x)."company", tab(x)."UK", y);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
                    ln_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
                    FOR i IN 1 .. ln_error_count LOOP
                        ln_line_error := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index;
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab(ln_line_error)."company" || ' ' || tab(ln_line_error)."UK" || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
                    END LOOP;
            END;
        END LOOP;

        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;     
    CLOSE my_cursor;

END;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18182580)

Comment: Thank you @max23_ for your comment. I've updated my post accordingly.